# Inclusions of closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X, Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces, $f : X \to Y$ a continuous function, $A \subseteq X$ closed and $B \subseteq Y$ closed. My conjecture is that
$$
\overline{f[A]} \cap B = \emptyset \quad\text{ iff }\quad A \cap f^{-1}[B] = \emptyset.
$$
Here $\overline{f[A]}$ is the closure of the direct image of $A$ under $f$. Is there a nice way to prove this?

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, $f[A]$ is automatically closed (in fact, it is even compact since $A$ is compact).

Comment: @Clayton, while $f(A)$ is closed, this is not just a direct consequence of continuity of $f$. Showing $f(A)$ is closed requires that X is compact and Y is Hausdorff, and goes via the fact that $f(A)$ is compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is a closed subset of a compact set, it is itself compact, so its image by $f$ is compact (thus closed). So your statement really reads
$$
f(A)\cap B = \emptyset \quad \text{iff}\quad A\cap f^{-1}(B) =\emptyset.
$$
By defining
$$
I = \{ (a,b)\in A\times B \text{ such that } f(a)=b\}
$$
one has $$f(A) \cap B = \{ b \in B \text{ such that } \exists a \in A \text{ such that } (a,b)\in I\}$$  and 
$$A \cap f^{-1}(B) = \{ a \in A \text{ such that } \exists b \in B \text{ such that } (a,b)\in I\}.$$
So both sides of your statement are equivalent to $I=\emptyset$.

Comment: Chila.Very nice.